# Translating Android app into English locales

Tags: android, localization

Is there a benefit of translating from English UK to USA and vice versa on the play store? Does this affect where your app is placed in ranking list of countries which aren't the default locale? I say this because the play store is saying I should translate my app to English US but there's hardly if at all a difference and it certainly wouldn't affect my app's usability so should I bother?

Answer (score 0):

In my experiences so far,

- the app that I use default as international gets priority to show up on Play app, not depending on users' phone locale.
- the app that I wrote for a specific country is found easily on that country's locale, I mean better ranking for specific localization.

I suggest to optimize for both, http://pcode.petehouston.com/2013/1226213/optimize-locales-for-android-apps/